# Block mails from my server to my server that are not in whitelist

Tags: email

I have a managed server lets call it `myserver.de`, where I could generate a list of all valid email addresses.

Now a lot of generated spam mails fake the sender address to something enerated like `max.mustermann@myserver.de`. This address is not valid, so I would like to block all addresses that have a `from` from myserver.de but are not in the allowed emails

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `reject_unlisted_sender` in `smtpd_sender_restrictions`.
see: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender

Or you can use  `check_sender_access` to blacklist mails that are from your server but not in that list.
see: http://www.linuxlasse.net/linux/howtos/Blacklist_and_Whitelist_with_Postfix

Comment: I am glad you found an answer and posted it here. I up-voted both the answer and question especially in light of the fact that you shared your answer with us. I Thank You for that! I wish I could up-vote more.